# allocator_traits example from cplusplus website

Tags: c++, gcc, allocator

I don't understant allocator_traits in C++ 11, so I tried the [allocator_traits exmple](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator_traits/) from cpluspluswebsite. However, this code can't compile in gcc 4.9, VS 2015, even not in its own website.

What's more, I also don't understand why I can't see any allocator_traits syntax in this example. I can just see this example build a custom allocator, then use the allocator in vector. Nothing about allocator_traits.

Can anyone help me?

```
// custom allocator example
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
struct custom_allocator {
  typedef T value_type;
  custom_allocator() noexcept {}
  template <class U> custom_allocator (const custom_allocator<U>&) noexcept {}
  T* allocate (std::size_t n) { return static_cast<T*>(::new(n*sizeof(T))); }
  void deallocate (T* p, std::size_t n) { ::delete(p); }
};

template <class T, class U>
constexpr bool operator== (const custom_allocator<T>&, const custom_allocator<U>&) noexcept
{return true;}

template <class T, class U>
constexpr bool operator!= (const custom_allocator<T>&, const custom_allocator<U>&) noexcept
{return false;}

int main () {
  std::vector<int,custom_allocator<int>> foo = {10,20,30};
  for (auto x: foo) std::cout << x << " ";
  std::cout << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

The compilation error in cplusplus website is:

```
 In member function 'T* custom_allocator<T>::allocate(std::size_t)':
12:74: error: expected type-specifier before ')' token
 In instantiation of 'T* custom_allocator<T>::allocate(std::size_t) [with T = int; std::size_t = long unsigned int]':
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/alloc_traits.h:357:32:   required from 'static std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::pointer std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::allocate(_Alloc&, std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::size_type) [with _Alloc = custom_allocator<int>; std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::pointer = int*; std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:170:46:   required from 'std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_allocate(std::size_t) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = custom_allocator<int>; std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = int*; std::size_t = long unsigned int]'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:1287:27:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_range_initialize(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::forward_iterator_tag) [with _ForwardIterator = const int*; _Tp = int; _Alloc = custom_allocator<int>]'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:378:36:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(std::initializer_list<_Tp>, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = custom_allocator<int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = custom_allocator<int>]'
25:57:   required from here
12:77: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
```

gcc 4.9 reports similar error.

VS 2015 reports error also in line 12. The message is below:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   allocator_traits    c:\users\jiang\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\allocator_traits\allocator_traits.cpp  12
```

Comment: cplusplus.com does not have a reputation for accuracy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `::new` by `::operator new` and it will work. Probably it was a typo on the website. You are calling here `operator new`, not invoking a `new` expression.

Comment: Can you answer my second question? Or can you explain this example a little bit?

Comment: I don't see any allocator traits being used either. This example seem to build a custom allocator and nothing more. You'd need to specialize [`std::allocator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) for your custom allocator. I'd recommend you use [`cppreference.com`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Main_Page), it seems to be of higher quality.

Comment: cppreference.com doesn't have example. Can you provide an example for me? I can't find an available  allocator_traits  example on the Internet.

Comment: @laijiang Unfortunately I am not very familiar with allocator_traits, maybe you can ask for a new question with an example on stackoverflow.

Comment: I asked the question, but the question is rates as off-topic. What should I do?

Comment: @laijiang Where is the question? You can simply ask to provide a simple example of an `allocator_traits`, I don't think it's off topic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110447/compilation-of-an-allocator-traits-example